# IndexError with keras.utils.to_categorical

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

Hi I'm building a deep learning model and I faced an Error:

```
 IndexError with keras.utils.to_categorical(
"IndexError: index 82 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10")
```

```
class dataGen():
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data

  def gen_splt_ind(self):

    p = np.random.permutation(len(self.data))
    train_up_to = int(len(self.data) * TRAIN_TEST_SPLIT)
    train_idx = p[:train_up_to]
    test_idx = p[train_up_to:]
    train_up_to = int(train_up_to * TRAIN_TEST_SPLIT)
    train_idx, valid_idx = train_idx[:train_up_to], train_idx[train_up_to:]
    return train_idx, valid_idx, test_idx

  def preprocess_image(self, img_path):
        """
        Used to perform some minor preprocessing on the image before inputting into the network.
        """
        im = Image.open(img_path)
        im = im.resize((IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT))
        im = np.array(im) / 255.0

        return im

  def generate_images(self, image_idx, is_training, batch_size=16):
        """
        Used to generate a batch with images when training/testing/validating our Keras model.
        """

        # arrays to store our batched data
        images, types, namess = [], [], []
        while True:
            for idx in image_idx:
                cars = self.data.iloc[idx]

                typ = cars['car_type']
                name = cars['car_code']
                file = cars['new_filename']

                im = self.preprocess_image(file)
                namess.append(name)
                types.append(typ)
                images.append(im)

                # yielding condition
                if len(images) >= batch_size:
                    print(namess)
                    namess = to_categorical(namess,len(cars_names))
                    print(namess)
                    print(types)
                    types  = to_categorical(types,len(car_types))
                    yield np.array(images), [np.array(types), np.array(namess)]
                    images, types, namess = [], [], []

            if not is_training:
                break



data_generator = dataGen(data)
train_idx, valid_idx, test_idx = data_generator.gen_splt_ind()
```

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
batch_size = 32
valid_batch_size = 32
train_gen = data_generator.generate_images(train_idx, is_training=True, batch_size=batch_size)
valid_gen = data_generator.generate_images(valid_idx, is_training=True, batch_size=valid_batch_size)
callbacks = [
    ModelCheckpoint("./model_checkpoint", monitor='val_loss')
]
history = model.fit(train_gen,
                    steps_per_epoch=len(train_idx)//batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    callbacks=callbacks,
                    validation_data=valid_gen,
                    validation_steps=len(valid_idx)//valid_batch_size)
```

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-130-20214718550a> in <cell line: 9>()
      7     ModelCheckpoint("./model_checkpoint", monitor='val_loss')
      8 ]
----> 9 history = model.fit(train_gen,
     10                     steps_per_epoch=len(train_idx)//batch_size,
     11                     epochs=epochs,

1 frames
<ipython-input-129-e88a0ded6aae> in generate_images(self, image_idx, is_training, batch_size)
     49                     print(namess)
     50                     print(types)
---> 51                     types  = to_categorical(types,len(car_types))
     52                     yield np.array(images), [np.array(types), np.array(namess)]
     53                     images, types, namess = [], [], []

IndexError: index 82 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10
```

when I fit the data into the model the Error above appear.

when I change the number of classes  in the to_categorical() it will work but in wrong num_classes.

Comment: Make sure that the number of the unique values in your types is equal to car_types, and they must start from 0. I suspect that some values are out-range [0-10[.